# Iterate Over Pandas DataFrame and Store Results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
columns = ['C24H31O8', 'C23H27O9', 'C22H23O10', 'C21H19O11', 'C20H15O12','C19H11O13']

values= [[   0.,   37.,   74.,  111.,  148.,  185.],
         [ -37.,    0.,   37.,   74.,  111.,  148.],
         [ -74.,  -37.,    0.,   37.,   74.,  111.],
         [-111.,  -74.,  -37.,    0.,   37.,   74.],
         [-148., -111.,  -74.,  -37.,    0.,   37.],
         [-185., -148., -111.,  -74.,  -37.,    0.]]
```

You can easily recreate my dataframe by using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=columns)
```

I want to iterate over my dataframe as follows:

While iterating, in row C24H31O8 you find 37 in column number 1. Now, go to row number 1 and iterate again. If you again find number 37 - in this case you find 37 in the third column - go to the third row and again search for 37 etc.

My desired output should be a chain:

```
37 : C24H31O9 --> C23H27O9 --> C22H23O10 --> C21H19O11 ...
```

(do something for every value)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if I understand the question correctly:

```
columns= pd.Index(['C24H31O8', 'C23H27O9', 'C22H23O10', 'C21H19O11', 'C20H15O12','C19H11O13'],dtype='object')

values=np.array([[   0.,   37.,   74.,  111.,  148.,  185.],
               [ -37.,    0.,   37.,   74.,  111.,  148.],
               [ -74.,  -37.,    0.,   37.,   74.,  111.],
               [-111.,  -74.,  -37.,    0.,   37.,   74.],
               [-148., -111.,  -74.,  -37.,    0.,   37.],
               [-185., -148., -111.,  -74.,  -37.,    0.]])

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns)

def build_string(df, i):
    row = 0
    chain = df.index[0]
    while True:
        try:
            row = df.iloc[row][df.iloc[row] == i].index[0]
            chain += f"--> {df.index[row]}"
        except IndexError:
            break
    return chain
```

**Output:**

```
>>> build_string(df, 37)
'C24H31O8--> C23H27O9--> C22H23O10--> C21H19O11--> C20H15O12--> C19H11O13'
```

or

```
>>> {int(i): build_string(df, i) for i in df.iloc[0] if i > 0}
{37: 'C24H31O8--> C23H27O9--> C22H23O10--> C21H19O11--> C20H15O12--> C19H11O13',
 74: 'C24H31O8--> C22H23O10--> C20H15O12',
 111: 'C24H31O8--> C21H19O11',
 148: 'C24H31O8--> C20H15O12',
 185: 'C24H31O8--> C19H11O13'}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = columns)
s = df.where(df>0).stack()
out_dict = s.index.get_level_values(1).groupby(s)
```

Output (`out_dict`):

```
{37.0: Index(['C23H27O9', 'C22H23O10', 'C21H19O11', 'C20H15O12', 'C19H11O13'], dtype='object'),
 74.0: Index(['C22H23O10', 'C21H19O11', 'C20H15O12', 'C19H11O13'], dtype='object'),
 111.0: Index(['C21H19O11', 'C20H15O12', 'C19H11O13'], dtype='object'),
 148.0: Index(['C20H15O12', 'C19H11O13'], dtype='object'),
 185.0: Index(['C19H11O13'], dtype='object')}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, When I try with a loop and iterate over all values, 37,74,111, I need to get different results, you are getting the same results and plus I dont know why I am stucking into infinite loop plus  you should edit the inside of the for loop 37 to i.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There's no loop in my code. You only need to extract, e.g. `out_dict[37.0]`?